# ajax won't trigger after form update

Tags: ajax, jsf, mojarra, jsf-2.2

Please see the following code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <p:inputText id="text" value="#{xTest.input}">

         <p:ajax process="text" update="searchResult" event="keyup" />

    </p:inputText>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="searchResult" style="border: none;">

         #{xTest.input}

    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGrid>
```

`xTest` is just a dummy bean with a field to hold the `input`, which is presented in the `panelGroup`.

Now this works fine as long as I don't update `@form` in the ajax tag. If I do, the ajax tag will fire the first keyup, but not after any subsequent. I've seen Balusc answer about commandLink/button problems: [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked) and maybe this has something to do with no 7 in that list. However, I don't understand it, and I would like to know what I can do to come around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my view JSF 2.2 was not properly released. It has some weird bugs and fixing times are quite slow at the moment. What I can tell you is that:

1. There are a few things that are working with the new namespaces and some that work with the old ones. You can try switching them and test
2. There are bugs with the jsf.js, especially if you are using multipart forms: see [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2871)
3. If you render a component that contains the form, try adding the form in the render as well `render='comp @form`. (might help)
4. I would suggest switching back to JSF 2.0 and migrating to 2.2.* when it is of adequate quality